# Why does my servlet request.getParameter return null

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to run following code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    int i = 1, j = 1;
    String title = "Web Movie";
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>" + title + "</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body");
    out.println("<h1>Seat Information</h1>");
    out.println("<center>");
    out.println("<form method='get' action='Theatre'> ");
    out.println("<table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=70%>");
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<th>Row</th>");
    out.println("<th colspan = 8>Seat</th>");
    out.println("</tr>");
    //Table hien thi thong tin ghe
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td style='text-align:center;'>" + (char)(i + 'A') + "</td>"); 
        for(j = 1; j < 9; j++) {                    
            out.println("<td  id = " + (char)(i + 'A') + j + " onclick='showResult(this.id);' style='text-align:center;'>" +  j + "</td>");      
        }   
        out.println("</tr>");   
    }
    out.println("</table>");
    out.println("</form>");
    out.println("<p>Vi tri ngoi:</p>");
    out.println("<input id = 'text2' name='Seat'><br>");
    out.println("<script>");
    out.println("function showResult(clicked_id){"); 
    out.println("document.getElementById('text2').value = clicked_id"); 
    out.println("}");
    out.println("</script>"); 
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    out.println(request.getParameter("Seat"));


}`
```

but getParameter always null.

Comment: When you access the URL mapped to the servlet, have you added the parameter "Seat" to it?

Comment: I don't know how to do it ? can you help me solve my problem : ((

Comment: Becasue the `Seat` parameter wasn't supplied.

Comment: post your jsp form code

Answer (score 0):

The only reason `request.getParameter("Seat")` will return you `null` is: The parameter `"Seat"` is not a part of request. Since it a GET request it should be a part of query string. Also the parmeter "Seat" is case sensitive.

Comment: Update the HTML/jsp page in the question

Answer (score 0):

If your servlet URL is http://server.com/context/myservlet, then you will need to add the "`Seat`" parameter to it. Here is how the toy URL should look like after adding the parameter:

http://server.com/context/myservlet?Seat=foo

So you have to add the expression `Seat=foo`, were `Seat` is the parameter name and `foo` it's value.

If you want to know more abot URL's check this page here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL